# Solr stopwords not working with wildcard search

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, stop-words, solrconfig

I am having problem with solr wildcard search and stopwords. I have added few stopwords "to", "for" ,"is" in stopwords.txt . When i am not doing a wildcard search , its working perfectly.
Query --> `q=learningObjectTopic:to&rows=1`

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">3</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">learningObjectTopic:to</str>
<str name="rows">1</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"/>
</response>
```

When i do a wildcard search its returning data .
Query --> `q=learningObjectTopic:*to*&rows=1`

```
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader">
<int name="status">0</int>
<int name="QTime">5</int>
<lst name="params">
<str name="q">learningObjectTopic:*to*</str>
<str name="rows">1</str>
</lst>
</lst>
<result name="response" numFound="75" start="0">
<doc>
<str name="id">56f4bc54b2de79277297dcab</str>
<str name="learningObjectId">LO1_SK1_18</str>
<str name="learningObjectTopic">Introduction to Web Development</str>
<str name="category">learningObject</str>
<long name="_version_">1537824533459763200</long>
</doc>
</result>
</response>
```

This is my analyzer

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" multiValued="false" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
```

What i require is , "to" should not match in the wildcard query too. What am i missing here ?

Note : learningObjectTopic:to search skipped "to" words in results when i added "to" in stopwords , so stopword indexing is working .

Comment: Does the field you search on have stored ="true" in schema.xml?
If so solr will store and return the original string - you'd need to check query analyzer to see how it is processing the stop words

Comment: @EricN This is my field definition
 `<field name="learningObjectTopic" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>`

Comment: Did you reindex after changing your analyzer definition?

Answer (score 0):

Solr StopFilterFactory is not a multi term aware component and hence stopFilterFactory will not work on for wildcard queries.[Reference link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultitermQueryAnalysis).

And also, the scenario may not be a valid one. since, if there is a keyword "Tokyo" in index, then the search keyword "to*" should return this result instead of showing "0" result **which is not correct**.

Comment: .. but since the stop word is removed _when indexing_, the query part should not match if there isn't a token matching `*to*` in the index?